# OpenFileDialog locks the file when trying to get the name of a sql database that it was open before in VB.NET Windows Form

Tags: sql, vb.net, openfiledialog

I have a sub in which I open sql databases through a OpenFileDialog. The problem arises when I try to re-open a database it was open before. Let me put an example:
I first open the database "mydatabase.mdf" -> Result OK
Then I open a second database "Seconddatabase.mdf" -> Result OK
Now, when I try to re-open "mydatabase.mdf", OpenFileDialog triggers an error and say "This file is being used. Write another name". Well, the message is not this,this is my translation into English, because in my system it is in Spanish "Este archivo está en uso. Escriba un nuevo nombre o cierre el archivo abierto en otro programa".
Well, the problem I am absolutely sure is caused by OpenFileDialog, because if I try the same process with an SaveFileDialog there is no file locking and I can open and reopen the database, but it's not a solution because the Dialog says the user to save file, not open.
I did another check by inserting a button control in which I re-open the first database hard-coded and it works, so the problem is in OpenFileDialog.
This is my code, but the code is not the problem (I think):

```
 Private Sub AbrirBaseDados()

    Dim fildia As New OpenFileDialog
            If fildia.ShowDialog() Then

        Try
            If fildia.FileName <> vbNullString Then
                pathBaseDados = (fildia.FileName)
                CadenaConexion = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" & pathBaseDados & ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Desconectar()
        fildia.Dispose()
    End If


End Sub
```

The sub doesn't throw an exception, it's just OpenDialogFile telling me that the file is being used and not allowing me to get the name of the file I want to open. Because ALL I WANT TO KNOW is the **name of the file of the db that the user specifies**, because knowing the name I can open it without problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why are using _OpenFileDialog_ for database ? Can't you use Sql* classes.. SqlConnection, SqlCommand etc. for that ?

Comment: OpenFileDialog is just the dialog with the user, to find out the name. Just to build the StringConnection (in my example, CadenaConexion). This sub is not opening anything, just getting the name of the file I want to open. The file is opened in another sub, that works.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear (I hope)

Comment: Are you properly disposing off database connection? You can add connection close code in your question. Did you try setting _fildia.ValidateNames = False_ ?

Comment: Yes, I'm closing the connection before trying to open. The only problem was the OpenFileDialog, but with the .ValidateNames = False trick, there is no problem and the program opens the database normally. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mdf is database file, **not** an ordinary file.

If you want to perform read write operations on database then read some tutorials first:

**[ADO.NET Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb)**

If you just want to get the names of database files from a given directory then use:

```
Dim filePaths As String() = Directory.GetFiles(YourFolderPath, "*.mdf")
```

**Edit:**

Use `openFileDialog.ValidateNames = False`:

```
Dim fildia As New OpenFileDialog
fildia.ValidateNames = False
```

Comment: Hi, Coder. I want to get the name of a database that the user specifies, not just all the names, that's why I'm using a OpenFileDialog. Being a database is not an issue, because, like I said, knowing the name I can open the database. The problem is telling OpenFileDialog to tell me the name of the file that the user wants to open, no matter what it thinks about the file is being used or not (which is not)

Comment: Thank you very much, Coder. This is what I was looking for! With the .validatenames= false, the OpenFileDialog work ;)